# "He's unsure what might come after" replacement?

Tags: phrases, prepositions

I am not a native English speaker and according to my classes, the phrase "He's unsure what might come after" is incorrect because it ends in a preposition. Is there a replacement for this sentence or is it fine as it is?

Comment: It's a myth that you can't end a sentence with a preposition. Ignore it. Your sentence is fine.

Comment: I don't think **after** is a preposition. What makes you think it is a preposition?

Comment: I think we need some extra context to decide whether it's well written or not. Is there any more surrounding text?

Comment: @Rathony "After" is a preposition.

Comment: @Max Williams Why? The sentence is well-formed.

Comment: @Rathony regardez: [link](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/after)

Comment: @BillJ context is everything.

Comment: @Max Williams The OP's question was a grammatical one about ending a sentence with a preposition. No one in 2016 still believes you can't. It's as simple as that!

Comment: @Rathony even if it were an adverb, the sentence is fine. So what are you bleating about?

Comment: @BillJ - The question does not say "It is ok to end a sentence with a preposition?" - that's **your take on it**.  The question says, I'm quoting, "Is there a replacement for this sentence or is it fine as it is?".  In order to answer this we need context.  It might be not-fine for reasons other than the one you're focussed on.  Do you think that it would **harm** the question, or people reading it, if some context was added?

Comment: @max Williams The OP mentions ending a sentence with a preposition, so the question is implied. They also ask if their sentence was fine as it is. The answer is yes to both. Deal with the question as submitted.

Comment: @Max Williams. Again, the sentence is fine; deal with it

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is fine as is.  Possible alternatives are "He's unsure what might come next." (same non-problem) or "He's unsure what might follow".